# Powershell : -match and \p

Tags: powershell, match

I have a textfile which contains a lot of adresses and stuff.
I need to know if this textfile contains an adress which is put in a String -lets call it "$adress"). To achieve that, I put the .txt in a variable "$list", and then use the -match operator to see if $list contains $adress.

```
if($list -Match $adress) {
            $test = "CONTAINS"
            $test
}
```

Problem is, it doesnt work at all. It looks like he cant deal with the "\p", which is a part of the adress. Is it supposed to do something ? I dont know how to deal with it.

Comment: Is the string in `$adress` properly escaped? Maybe show us the actual value

Comment: O:\folder\public\Data;1030.95;812.7;79;08/13/2013 13:28:49;11/25/2015 02:02:28
This is a line of the textfile. The adress would be : O:\folder\public\Data

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to escape that, otherwise `\\` will be interpreted as regex escape sequences and not actual characters

Answer (score 0):

The `-match` operator uses regular expressions. That means that any backslash followed by a character is interpreted as an escape sequence, and not a literal character.

You can escape special characters (including slashes) in your pattern with the [`Regex.Escape()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
if($list -match [regex]::Escape($adress)){
    "List contains at least one string matching $adress"
}
```